# iPod Classic - Disc 1 and 2 of a double album are not consecutive in the cover flow

Tags: itunes, ipod

Some double albums correctly imported via iTunes are then not correctly diplayed in the cover flow. Disc 1 and Disc 2 of double albums are not consecutive despite the information, names etc are correctly uploaded.

How to get such albums displayed in sequence using the cover flow option?
Thank you for any contribution
Have a good day
Alessandro

Comment: Do you have either of these songs/albums as 'Part of a compilation'?  Look at the songs/albums and see if there's a checkbox by this option.  If so, delete the check and see if that helps then post back.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. No I never use that feature but I will check if it has not been checked by accident.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I import a two disc set into iTunes, I edit the metadata so that the album names match across the two discs, rather than having disc numbers as part of each album name. It is still easy to see which disc is which because the metadata includes disc numbers (separate from the track numbers) which are independent of the album name.

As I recall an iPod sorts first by disc number and then by track number (or maybe iTunes does that and the iPod inherits the result), so the tracks play in what seems like the correct order.

Comment: Hello Eirik, thank you. I'll check that as well. Some double albums have  been imported with the DIsc [1] and Disc [2] notes in the description and are correctly displayed  while other with the same description are displayed in different positions.

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly the iPod decides to order albums, but I wonder if there is a way to affect that within iTunes. I seem to remember playlists can be reordered from iTunes (by clicking column headers), and that reordering takes effect on the iPod after a sync. Perhaps album ordering can be similarly manipulated using iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved the problem, but no matter where you get the tracks from (internet, cd etc) the tags can be wrong. A space at the end of the name results in two different albums or artists, and this is not immediately visible. You should select the tracks in iTunes, go to File>Get info and give all of them the same artist, album, date etc and in the fields "disc" enter (for example in a 3-disc release) 1 of 3 for the first, 2 of 3 for the second, 3 of 3 for the last.
Please note that the tags you change/see in iTunes have nothing to do with the file names you see in the directory, desktop or wherever they're stored.